# How can I wirelessly take photos on an original 5d?

Tags: wireless-triggers

Te original 5D does not support the incredibly handy IR remotes that are on the market. What are the viable alternatives for remote shooting?

Comment: Radiowaves wireless works up to 300 feet. [Pixel Oppilas](http://www.pixelhk.com/Proshow.aspx?id=300) wireless shutter release has Canon 5D supported (with N3 cable plug). Just yesterday I ordered one for my Sony SLT camera, so I don't have it yet to tell you more. Amazon price is below $30.

Answer (score 1):

There are triggers available that use the N3 cable release connector on your 5D to accomplish wireless shutter release. The receiver plugs into the camera just as a wired cable release would and the camera sees it as such. When you press the button on the transmitter the receiver fires the camera's shutter just as a wired cable release would. Here is [one such trigger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002X7FSO6) available from amazon.

Many triggers available to do this, such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004YTA15W), also have the capability to be used as manual *flash triggers*. One-way triggers will only fire the flash without allowing any communication between the camera and flash. In fact the camera will not even detect there is a flash connected, just as when a non E-TTL compatible third party flash is mounted on the 5D's hot shoe. This means you will need to set the flash's power manually and probably means you will need to set the exposure settings on your camera in Manual mode.

Answer (score 0):

I use yongnuo wireless triggers. I bought three units for £30 on ebay. Granted they are a budget radio trigger, but I have never had any issues with mine. The range is good and can trigger your camera or be used with your flash. They work with my 7D so is presume they will be compatible with a 5D as well. Check out their eviews on youtube if your not sure about them